# Simple Algebraic Extension Divisibility

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've been trying to come up with a simple algebraic extension $F(\alpha)$ over a field $F$ that has $[F(\alpha):F]$ not divisible by 3, but has $F(\alpha^3)$ properly contained in $F(\alpha)$.  I haven't had any luck - maybe I'm thinking incorrectly, but all I can think of is cube roots, fourth roots and the like.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{R}(i)$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, I'm looking for proper containment.  $\mathbb{R}(i^3)=\mathbb{R}(i)$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word 'properly'.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make sense to me. Perhaps you mean to say $F(\alpha)$ is a simple extension over $F$? If that's the case, what is $E$ doing?

Comment: Although this does not help if $E$ is not supposed to be $F$ in one spot and $F(\alpha)$ in another, an example might be $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ where $\omega=\mathrm{exp}(2\pi i/3)$, since $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$.

Comment: I apologize there, I fixed it.

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, not to nitpick, but [the standard notation for the degree of an extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension) $L/K$ is $[L:K]$, i.e. the larger field is on the left. Now that I think I understand what you're asking, I'll edit.

Comment: @hwhm: $[F(\alpha) : F(\alpha^3)]$ is not necessarily $3$.

Comment: I attempted to answer the question, but given the hour its best if someone reviews it

Comment: @peoplepower: I think it'd be great if you put that comment as answer now that the question is cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the extension $\mathbb Q(\omega)/\mathbb Q$ with $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, and note that $\omega$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. Since $\omega$ is distinct from $1$, it must satisfy $p(x)=x^2+x+1$. Finally, $p(x+1)=x^2+3x+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's Criterion.

Therefore the extension is a degree 2, simple extension generated by a cube root of an element of the base field.

Comment: Looks OK to me, +1